# Knockout-Validation multiple custom async rules

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a domain property and I want to validate two things;

1. URL exists (is reachable)
2. URL exists in my local DB.

In order to check these things I created to async validation rules using https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation and applied both of them on my property.

What happens is that each time the response from one of the rules comes earlier and it sets `isValidating` property to `false` and I want this property to be `true` until the response from my second rule came.

1. Custom rules:

   ```
    export function enableCustomValidators() {
       (ko.validation.rules as any)["urlValidationServicePath"] = {
       async: true,
       validator: function (url: string, baseUrl: string, callback: any) {
           getRequest(url, baseUrl, callback, "true");
       },
       message: 'You must enter a reachable domain.',
   },
   (ko.validation.rules as any)["customerValidationServicePath"] = {
       async: true,
       validator: function (url: string, baseUrl: string, callback: any) {
           getRequest(url, baseUrl, callback, "false");
       },
       message: "This url already exists in our system. Please contact us at hello@ve.com",
   }

   ko.validation.registerExtenders();
   }

   function getRequest(url: string, baseUrl: string, callback: any, method: string) {
       var restClient = new RestClient();
       restClient.downloadString(baseUrl.concat(url), (responseText) => {
           method === "true" ? callback(responseText === "true" ? true : false) :
               callback(responseText === "true" ? false : true);
   });
   }
   ```
2. Using of the rules:

   ```
   export class CompanySetupVM extends BasePageVM {
       public websiteUrl: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable(undefined);
       public isValidating: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = ko.observable(false);

       public constructor() {
           this.websiteUrl.extend({
               required: {
               params: true,
               message: CompanySetupVM.ErrorMessageNullWebsiteUrl
           },
           urlValidationServicePath: CompanySetupVM.DomainValidationPath,
           customerValidationServicePath: CompanySetupVM.CustomerValidationPath
           });
           this.isValidating = ko.computed(() => this.websiteUrl.isValidating(), this);   
       }
   }
   ```
3. In cshtml:

   ```
    data-bind="text: currentPage().nextButtonText, css: {'button-overlay': currentPage().isValidating(), 'button': !currentPage().isValidating()}, click: nextAction"
   ```

Comment: You need to show your code. Nobody can point out your mistake just by concentrating very hard.

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at the source code of knockout validation ([here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/src/extenders.js)) and it's pretty clear that two independent async validators are not supported.

The `isValidating` property is set to `true` as soon as an async rule is begins to run and set to `false` again as soon as that rule finishes. Therefore, multiple async rules clash.

There is only one solution. Remove the second async validator.

You can collapse the two checks into one either on the client side or on the server side.

To do it on the client side, you would need to write a validator that runs two Ajax requests and invokes the validation `callback` only after both of them have returned.

To do it on the server side, you would have to run the "is reachable" and "is in DB" checks in succession before giving an overall response to the client.

Personally I would prefer changing the server side, because

1. it keeps the client code tidy and manageable
2. it saves one HTTP round-trip per check
3. semantically, the URL check is *one thing* that fail for more than one reason
4. it's easy to let the server send a custom validation result and -message

Besides plain `true` or `false`, the validation plugin understands responses in this format:

```
{isValid: false, message: "something is wrong"}
```

So make your server send a JSON response with the appropriate validation result and error message and your REST client download JSON instead of text.

Then all you need to do is pass the server's response directly to the validation callback.

```
ko.validation.rules.urlValidationServicePath = {
    async: true,
    validator: function (url, baseUrl, callback) {
        restClient.downloadJSON(baseUrl.concat(url), callback);
    },
    message: 'The URL you entered is not valid.'
};
```

Here the `message` is only a default. The server's `message` always takes precedence over the setting in the validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Tomalak pointed out it is not possible to have multiple async validators. But I solved it on the client side and solution is quite manageable and flexible IMHO.
The trick here is to implement different async validators as regular knockout extenders and having single async rule to call them. Here is the async rule:

```
interface HasAsyncValidator {
    asyncValidators: Validator[];
}

interface Validator {
    name: string,
    validator: (params: any) => boolean | PromiseLike<any>,
    params: any
}

interface KnockoutObservable<T> extends HasAsyncValidator {}

ko.validation.rules["validateAsync"] = {
validator: async (value: any, paramsAccessor: () => HasAsyncValidator, callback: (result: boolean | ValidationResult) => void) => {
    const params = paramsAccessor();
    if (!params || !params.asyncValidators) {
        callback(true);
        return;
    }

    try {
        const results = await Promise.all(params.asyncValidators.map(v => v.validator(v.params)));
        const invalidResult = results.find(r => r.isValid === false);
        callback(!!invalidResult ? invalidResult : true);
    } catch (error) {
        callback(false);
        throw error;
    }
},
message: 'default message',
async: true
}
```

As you can see, we extended observable with asyncValidators property, which keeps all the registered validators. All that is left for the rule is just call validators (if any) and then pass result to the knockout validation callback.
Here is an example of validator as regular extender:

```
ko.extenders["validationRule"] = (target: any, option: any) => {
    const validatorObj: Validator = {
        name: "validationRule",
        params: option,
        validator: async (): Promise<boolean | ValidationResult> => {
            const unwrappedValue = ko.unwrap(target);
            const result = await callServer();
            return {
                isValid: result.isValid,
                message: result.message
            };
        }
    }
    addOrUpdateAsyncValidator(target, validatorObj);
};

function addOrUpdateAsyncValidator(target: HasAsyncValidator, validatorObj: Validator) {
    target.asyncValidators = target.asyncValidators || [];
    
    const existingRule = target.asyncValidators.find(v => v.name == validatorObj.name);
    !!existingRule
        ? existingRule!.params = validatorObj.params
        : target.asyncValidators.push(validatorObj);
}
```

Note that each validator must register itself to asyncValidators property on observable.

The usage of this solution is quite straightforward:

```
let value = ko.observable();
value.extend({ validationRule: true, validateAsync: () => value });
```

Note that we should pass value accessor to the validateAsync instead of value itself. That is needed so async rule don't miss validators that can be added later.